# How to disable iPhone notifications from Facebook Places?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, facebook

I've got this long-running annoyance about the Facebook iPhone app.

Now, I **do** want notifications from Facebook e.g. when someone posts on my wall/timeline or mentions me in a comment.  However, every now and again, some of my friends check in (or whatever it's technically called) somewhere with Facebook, and I get a big alert about it:

[image]

I most certainly do not want *these* notifications! And I don't really follow why Facebook considers someone's random check-in an event that *I* should be notified about.

Question is, **how can I disable these**—or all Facebook Places related notifications, while at it? Are there any settings on the Facebook website related to this?

<s>I'm asking at Webapps SE, and not e.g. Apple SE, because</s> I'm pretty sure the iPhone app doesn't have any related settings. The only FB notification setting I see is this one:

[image]

(...and as said, I wouldn't want to turn off *all* FB notifications.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong; you *can* configure this on iPhone.

As **[the guide on this page](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Facebook-Places-Notifications-on-Your-iPhone)** taught me:

1. Open Settings
2. Scroll down to the application list and select Facebook
3. Choose Push Notifications

Now, in my case it was probably **Nearby Friends** that I mostly wanted to disable. I ended up turning off some others too:

[image]

Comment: Once again, [rubber-ducking](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) with Stack Exchange got the problem solved. :)

Answer (score -1):

This has been driving me crazy because the notifications show up in the web browser Facebook, but the settings can only be accessed and turned off from the Facebook iOS app.

Note that the Facebook app has a new UI and that these settings are now inside the iOS app. I already had all Facebook iOS notifications off.

Even worse, Facebook's notion of what's nearby makes no sense for an urban area. 15 miles away, across the bridge, who cares? Stop notifying me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I too recently saw one of these notifications *in the normal Facebook web UI*... So do you know any way to turn those off, or are you basically asking a follow-up question?

Answer (score -1):

here is how to remove it : go to your facebook on your phone; slide to the right so you can see newsfeed, messages, etc etc , go to Account Setting, then go to Notifications, then go to Mobile Push, then uncheck NEARBY FRIENDS.......There you have it !!!

Comment: that didnt work I already had neaby friends unchecked